# Show variable within TWIG short form if/else statement with HTML

Tags: php, html, twig

```
{{r.status == 'active' or 'scheduled' ? 'The order status is <a href="https://example.com/"> 
{{r.order}} : 'The order status is cancelled'</a>'
```

When using the line above it prints {{r.order}} instead of the value from the variable. How can I print the value?

Comment: No, sorry. Did some research myself, but can't find a way to the print the twig {{r.order}} variable

Comment: Where do you close `{{r.status` ?

Comment: You are right. Missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [`in` operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#containment-operator) combined with [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) and the [`raw` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html):

```
{{r.status in ['active', 'scheduled'] 
  ? "The order status is <a href=\"https://example.com/\">#{r.order}</a>"|raw 
  : 'The order status is cancelled'}}
```

**Demo: https://twigfiddle.com/tj2skl**

Comment: Tried, the code, but it still prints {{r.order}} instead of the value within my code.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case, as you can see from the fiddle. What version of Twig are you using? Also, what does `r.order` contain?

Comment: Also, I had `'cancelled'` instead of `'scheduled'`. Fixed now.

Comment: @stew - Make sure you are using `#{r.order}` and not `{{ r.order }}` like in your initial code